# The performance of SFINAE and if else

Tags: c++, performance, cpu, sfinae

I've known that `if else` could generate the [Pipeline stall (bubble)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_stall) because the Branch predictor can't keep right-guessing 100%. In a word, lots of `if elif elif ... else` has a bad performance.

In the template of C++, we have [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). With the SFINAE, we can avoid `if else` code. For example, to check if an int is odd or not, we can code as below:

```
template <int I> void div(char(*)[I % 2 == 0] = 0) {
    // this overload is selected when I is even
}
template <int I> void div(char(*)[I % 2 == 1] = 0) {
    // this overload is selected when I is odd
}
```

so that we avoid

```
if (I % 2 == 0)
{
    // do things
}
else
{
    // do other things
}
```

My question is, does SFINAE has a better performance comparing with `if else`? does SFINAE can avoid the Pipeline bubble?

Comment: Easier to maintain version: `template <int I> void div() { div_helper<I%2>(); }`  Now write `template<> div_helper<0>` and `template<> div_helper<1>`.  SFINAE not needed.

Comment: SFINAE is a C++98 technique. We now have `if constexpr`. But as Joseph Sible's answer points out, it's often not necessary because optimizers can insert that `constexpr` themselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a runtime performance perspective, it literally doesn't matter at all which one you do. Either `I` is knowable at compile time, in which case any half-decent compiler will output the same constant case for both, or it isn't, in which case the SFINAE way won't compile at all.